# EF Migrations with multi-project AWS Lambda solution in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'm pretty sure this is a DI configuration question specific to the AWS Lambda project template in VS.

I have a .NET 6 solution with multiple projects (Clean Architecture). For the purposes of this question, there are two projects:

`ProjectName.Lambdas.Aggregator` - based on the AWS Lambda template in Visual Studio. References `ProjectProjectName.Infrastructure`.

`ProjectProjectName.Infrastructure` - Holds all of the EF references, context class, entities, etc.

The function entrypoint triggers the DI configuration.

I'll paste relevant code below (any code not related to this question has been removed).

My question is: When I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration` (I'm setting the project of the migration to the Infrastructure project and the startup project to my Lambda function) I get the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'SolutionName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.Persistence.Relational.Postgres.ApplicationContext'`

What I *think* is happening is that because this is an AWS Lambda project, the `FunctionHandler` entry point (whose constructor initializes the DI container) is not called during a migration, therefore it has no idea how to inject `DbContextOptions`.

**How do I get migrations to work in this setup?**

**Startup.cs**

```
using SolutionName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.Persistence.Relational.Postgres;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace SolutionName.ProjectName.SessionAggregator;

public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    public Startup()
    {
        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationContext")));

        IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        return provider;
    }
}
```

**Function.cs**

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents;
using SolutionName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.Persistence.Relational.Postgres;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace SolutionName.ProjectName.SessionAggregator;

public class Function
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public Function()
    {
        var startup = new Startup();
        IServiceProvider provider = startup.ConfigureServices();

        _context = provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();
    }
    
    public async Task FunctionHandler(SQSEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        foreach (var message in evnt.Records)
        {
            await ProcessMessageAsync(message, context);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(SQSEvent.SQSMessage message, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        context.Logger.LogInformation($"Processed message {message.Body}");

        // TODO: Do interesting work based on the new message
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationContext.cs**

```
using SolutionName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.Persistence.Relational.Postgres.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SolutionName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.Persistence.Relational.Postgres;

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<SessionEntity> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found a series of blog posts that answered my question. It's a bit too involved to summarize here. I'm going to post links to the three blog posts, I guess a moderator can delete this question if/when the blog posts go down:

Part 1: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/16/add-net-core-di-and-config-goodness-to-aws-lambda-functions/

Part 2: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/20/idesigntimedbcontextfactory-and-dependency-injection-a-love-story/

Part 3: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/21/use-ef-core-with-aws-lambda-functions/